# React 2 ouside events cannot share hook data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I have 2 outside events, `input` and `keydown` for an input element, when input fired, it will call `setInput` in React component. When `keydown` event for `arrowDown` fired, ideally the input value should be the one set inside `handleInput`, but it's empty, do I miss something?

```
const SearchBox : React.FunctionComponent<ISearchProps> = React.memo((props: ISearchProps) => {
   const [input, setInput] = React.useState({value: '', redirect: false});

    useEffect(() => {
        const container = document.querySelector('.xxx');
        container.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
        container.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardEvent);
    }, []);

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setInput({value: e.currentTarget.value, redirect: false});
    }

    const handleKeyboardEvent = (e) => {
        switch (e.key) {
            case 'ArrowDown':
                console.log(input);
                setActiveSuggestionIndex(activeSuggestionIndex === suggestions.length - 1 ? 0 : activeSuggestionIndex + 1);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you are calling the events is not very ReactJS way, but try switching to this: `setInput({...input, value: e.currentTarget.value, redirect: false});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

This is an issue of stale enclosures of state in a callback function. The initial `input` state value of `{ value: '', redirect: false }` is closed over in the copy of  `handleKeyboardEvent` from the initial render cycle. It will never update.

## Solutions

### Use React ref and `useEffect` to cache a copy of value

Use a React ref and an additional `useEffect` hook to cache a value to be accessed asynchronously in the callback.

```
const [input, setInput] = React.useState({ value: '', redirect: false });
const inputRef = React.useRef(input); // <-- state cache

useEffect(() => {
  const container = document.querySelector('.xxx');
  container.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
  container.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardEvent);

  return () => {
    container.removeEventListener('input', handleInput);
    container.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardEvent);
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  inputRef.current = input; // <-- update state cache value
}, [input]);

const handleInput = (e) => {
  setInput({ value: e.currentTarget.value, redirect: false });
};

const handleKeyboardEvent = (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    case 'ArrowDown':
      console.log(inputRef); // <-- read current state cache value

      setActiveSuggestionIndex(activeSuggestionIndex => 
        activeSuggestionIndex === suggestions.length - 1
          ? 0
          : activeSuggestionIndex + 1
      );
      e.preventDefault();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

### Use `useEffect` with dependency and cleanup function

Since you should also already be returning a cleanup function from the `useEffect` to remove the event listeners when unmounting, add the `input` state to the dependency array (*and any other missing dependencies the linter may complain about*) so that when the `input` state updates, the current state value is re-enclosed in callback scope.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setInput({ value: e.currentTarget.value, redirect: false });
  };

  const handleKeyboardEvent = (e) => {
    switch (e.key) {
      case 'ArrowDown':
        console.log(input);

        setActiveSuggestionIndex(activeSuggestionIndex => 
          activeSuggestionIndex === suggestions.length - 1
            ? 0
            : activeSuggestionIndex + 1
        );
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const container = document.querySelector('.xxx');

  container.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
  container.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardEvent);

  return () => {
    container.removeEventListener('input', handleInput);
    container.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardEvent);
  };
}, [input]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but seems not re-rendering after changing into useRef, is there any way to re-render?

Comment: @Lei Welcome. Can you clarify for me what isn't rerendering? The use of React refs is sort of *outside* the react component lifecycle, in other words, refs are like mutable "buckets" you can store any value in that persists *through* render cycles.

Comment: thanks for the explaination, I wonder if I can use useRef and also to see if there's a way that I can re-render DOM (like useState)? Like manual call re-render, because that updated "input" needs to be re-rendered, I don't want to keep 2 copies (one useRef, the other use useState).

Comment: @Lei Oh, did you remove the `input` state from the `useState` hook? You still need that so you can update state and trigger the rerenders.

Comment: @Lei There is an alternative I can show you if interested, for the sake of completeness I suppose.

Comment: I looked into docs, the useRef will not do re-rendering, if you have alternative way, that will be great! I just wanna "input" value can be shared between 2 outside events and do rendering

Comment: @Lei That's kind of the point of the ref, it can be read from/mutated at any time and doesn't trigger rerenders, but that is why having and updating local state is still necessary. I updated my answer with an alternative to use *just* the state, but at the expense of adding/removing the even listeners each time the state updates. I think using the ref is a more clean and optimal solution, but that's also ***just my opinion ‍♂️***, others are free to choose otherwise.